# Area of closed curve $\gamma $ : $ \frac{1}{2} \oint_{\gamma} (\gamma \times T \cdot B ds)$

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, frenet-frame

I want to extend the area formula of the closed curve as follows :

First for some curve $C(t) = (x(t), y(t))$. I know by Green's theorem, then the area have the following form :

\begin{align}A = \iint_A dx \, dy = \frac{1}{2} \oint_C (-y\, dx + x\, dy) = \frac{1}{2} \oint_C \vec{F}\cdot d\vec{r}
\end{align}

where $\vec{F}=(-y,x,0)$ and $d\vec{r} = (dx,dy,dz)$.  Note one can treat $\vec{F} = \hat{n} \times \vec{r}$ where $\hat{n}$ is the unit normal vector and $\vec{r}=(x,y,z)$.  [Since we are considering $xy$ plane $\hat{n} = (0,0,1)$]

I want to express this with $\gamma$ and Fernet-Serret formulas, i.e., $T,B,N$

From somewhere else, I found
\begin{align}
A = \frac{1}{2} \oint_{\gamma} \gamma \times T \cdot B ds
\end{align}
where $T$ is tangent vector and $B$ is binormal vector. Is this formula right? (For simple case as circle $(r\sin(t), r\cos(t))$ this formula seems work) And How one proves this?

Comment: $\vec r = (x,y,0)$. $B=\hat n = (0,0,1)$. Just compute $\gamma\times (\vec T\,ds) = (x,y,0)\times (dx,dy,0)$ (to use your notation).